# Waiting for executoro to finish while tasks can submit more tasks

Tags: python-multithreading, python-3.6, threadpoolexecutor

I submitting tasks to a ThreadPoolExecutor, while those tasks can submit more tasks in some cases. I want to wait until all tasks are finished. I have a solution for that using a `condition` over the internal queue size of the `executor`, but though it works, I feel it is not the best approach.

Here is an example for what I'm doing, I reduced it to a very simple case:

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from threading import Condition


def func(e: ThreadPoolExecutor, c: Condition, val: int):
    print(val)
    if val < 5:
        # A case when I need to submit a new task
        e.submit(func, e, c, val + 1)
    with c:
        c.notify()


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as e:
    c = Condition()
    for i in range(10):
        print(e._work_queue.qsize())
        e.submit(func, e, c, 1)
    with c:
        while not e._work_queue.qsize() == 0:
            c.wait_for(lambda: e._work_queue.qsize() == 0)
```

Is there a better and/or cleaner way to do that?